# Free structure and the heap

Tags: c

If we have a structure that has pointers to malloced memory and then if we free that structure, is the memory referenced by that structure also freed? or do we have to free it manually? eg:

```
typedef struct{
    FOMResult *fomResult;
    HOMResult *homResult;
} MResult;
```

where FOMResult and HOMResult are both structs.

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, if you allocate memory, you must free it explicitly somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the memory referenced by that structure also freed? or do we have to free it manually?

The latter.

Each memory block dynamically allocated needs a separate call to `free()`.

Comment: Think about it. As far as free() is concerned, it's just a block of memory. It has no idea that you happen to contain pointers to other blocks that need to be freed.

Comment: I know.. also am I required to free memory if the program end.. like if I dont free any memory at all for memory that is only used once, like I only have one instance of that structure.. it will be freed automatically when the program terminates?

Comment: @kingkong: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488099/why-do-i-need-to-delete/15489737#15489737

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to free memory pointed by `fomResult` and `homResult` before you free your `MResult`, otherwise you'll end up with memory leak.

Of course if you have other pointer to those memory blocks you can use them to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically equals to number of `malloc()`s performed to allocate the memory. If you allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()` for both struct pointers `fomResult` & `fomResult` you should use separate two `free()` functions to free there memory along with freeing `MResult`.