# what happens to malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

Well I think I know the answer to the question but I rather be assured. If you malloc memory on the heap and exit the program before you free the space does the os or compiler free the space for you ?

Comment: Modern OS do free the memory after the program termination.

Comment: The OS has to do it.  The compiler cannot do it because it's not there.  The app code it generated cannot do it because it may have crashed or just got stuck and been forcibly terminated by kill-9 or Task Manager.

Comment: It may also be that the app is not even designed to try to do it because it's just too complex a job and the OS can do it completely and correctly with one call.

Comment: This question might be of interest to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488099/why-do-i-need-to-delete/15489737#15489737

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS free the space for you when it removes the process's descriptor (`task_struct` in Linux's case) from its process list.

The compiler usually generates an [`exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit) system call and there's where all this is handled.

On Linux, basically, all these happens in the kernel's `exit_mm()` function, eventually invoked by `exit()`. It will release the address space owned by the process with `mm_release()` function. All that source is available for you to read (although it might get a little complicated :) But yes, the operating system is in charge of releasing process's resources.

And just because I like it so much, if you're into these topics, this is a very GOOD reading: [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000028.do).

Answer (score 3):

That is outside the scope of the C standard. What happens depends on the system. On all common mainstream operative systems, the OS will free the memory when the process is done.

Still, it is good practice to always clean up your own mess. So no matter what the OS does, you should always free up all resources you were using. Doing so is also an excellent way to spot hidden runtime bugs: if you have bugs, the program might crash when you try to free the resources and thereby alerting the programmer of the bugs.

As for the compiler, it is only active during program creation, it has absolutely nothing to do with the runtime execution of your program.

Comment: 'So no matter what the OS does, you should always free up all resources you were using' - no, not really.   Attempting to so so when it is not necessary means writing more code.  Writing more code means writing more bugs, debugging more bugs and more testing.  Writing more code to 'cleanly shut down' a complex, multithreaded system, in those cases where it is unnecessary to do so, is not justifiable.

Comment: @MartinJames If your complex multi-threaded system cannot be easily shut down, I would say that's an indication of poor program design. If you have a situation of "My own code is so complex that I have no idea what it is doing, let alone how to stop it. Help! Where is the emergency stop!?"... I would say that you have a _very poor_ program design. Also, in the specific case of threads, living threads may cause the process to remain running as a ghost when it should be dead.

Comment: @MartinJames: A program which cannot be shut down cleanly is an impediment to finding flaws such as memory leaks; a memory leak detector will be overwhelmed with false positives. But you are right that there is little point in sweeping the floors before the building is demolished. I encourage doing both: write the code to clean up for normal shutdown procedures, and be willing to abandon everything in a hurry in the event of an abnormal shutdown.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488099/why-do-i-need-to-delete/15489737#15489737

Comment: @Lundin my 'poor designed' multi-threaded systems, (ie,. those without unnecessary explicit shutdown code),  all work fine and they all shut down immediately when requested.  My code is not necessarily 'too complex' it's just that I have no idea what it is doing at any one time.  The data flowing all over the place in an indeterminate stream of messages and buffers is why it is not possible to easily appreciate what is going on at any one time and so makes it difficult to design and implement efficient shutdown systems.

Comment: Also, ' 'living threads may cause the process to remain running as a ghost' - what living threads?  Teminating a process from any thread requests the OS to stop all threads on all cores, no matter what state they are in, before releasing process resources. User code cannot stop all threads in any state - it does not have access to the inter-core driver required to stop a thread running on another core.  If anything is 'poorly designed', it is apps using unnecessary, over-complicated and buggy shutdown code instead of relying on an OS that has had decades of testing.

Comment: As for memory leak detection tools, I just don't bother.  I try very hard indeed to get all my malloc/new done at startup - creating buffer and object instance pools so that such things can be recycled and the pool levels continually monitored as the app runs.  I do get object/struct leaks, but I notice it while the app is running without any 3rd-party leak detectors.  I don't leak threads either because, like the buffer/object pools, they are all started when the app is and never explicitly terminated, ie. no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The OS will clear all resources consumed by your program, including all allocated memory, network connections, filehandles etc.